# SVN Commit over vpn not working on home network

Tags: vpn, svn, commit

I have a vpn connection to my work place, where I have an svn repository with my code. I am trying to commit changes on my local drive to the remote repository with TortoiseVPN. When I connect from my home adsl connection (plus the vpn), the commit always fails. However, I have tried sharing my cell phone's connection (plus the vpn) and it works just fine.

Any guess as to what may be happening?

Comment: We need more information than "it failed" numerous reasons it could fail and most of the time the logs tell you the reason

Comment: By "it fails" I mean that it won't connect. I hangs infinitely and when I cancel it, it says that it could not connect with the repository.

Answer (score 1):

May be your home fire wall is blocking svn transfer. You need to have special ports open for svn depending on the protocol you are using.

What's the first part of your Subversion repository URL?

- SVN-URL: `http://subversion/repos/` -> Port 80
- SVN-URL: `https://subversion/repos/` -> Port 443
- SVN-URL: `svn://subversion/` -> Port 3690
- SVN-URL: `svn+ssh://subversion/repos/`-> Port 22
- SVN-URL: `http://subversion/repos:8080` -> Port 8080

for more info see here:
[svn question on similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249097/what-ports-need-to-be-open-for-svn-tortoise-to-authenticate-clear-text-and-com)

Comment: Yes, I saw that post, but it's not my case. My url is of the first type "http://subversion/repos/", but port 80 is open.

Comment: can you access the repository by a browser under that url?

Answer (score 1):

`route -p add REPO-IP mask 255.255.255.255 GATEWAY metric 1`

- `REPO-IP` is your SVN repository host IP (just ping it)
- `GATEWAY` is your default gateway shown via `ipconfig /all`